# InternJS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, intern

I am using Intern.js to do functional testing and ran into the error in the title. I have no clue how to load json files through FS or through require. I tried everything on Google.

Here's the code in question.

```
var fs = require('intern/dojo/node!fs')

fs.readFile('./test.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err; // we'll not consider error handling for now
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Comment: It's unclear how much context you're leaving out of that code.  Are you wrapping that in an AMD define, as shown in [the examples](http://theintern.github.io/intern/#testing-commonjs-code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way to make it work:

```
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'intern/dojo/node!fs'
],
function(registerSuite, assert, fs) {
    ...
});
```

Idea from here: 
[How do I load the node.js http module from within an intern.js test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266469/how-do-i-load-the-node-js-http-module-from-within-an-intern-js-test)